# Is there a way to migrate a question to a SE site not on the "belongs on" list?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, vote-to-close

Is there a way to vote a question "belongs on" a StackExchange site, that is not one of the sites provided in the `close > off topic` menu?

Comment: There's a much more detailed explanation in our FAQ [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work). Specifically, it goes through when it's appropriate and when not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flag -> "it needs ♦ moderator attention" -> "other"

Type in a short message explaining which site you think it belongs on.

Comment: But I want to close the question and there is an other option on off topic page it should be possible to put it there.