# Move a question from Super User to Tex.SE?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to migrate a question to a SE site not on the “belongs on” list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82104/how-to-migrate-a-question-to-a-se-site-not-on-the-belongs-on-list)

I found a question on Super User that belongs on the Tex Stack Exchange.

Is it possible to flag it as such, or does this question have to go through Stack Overflow in order to reach its destination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all SE sites are listed in the list when you flag as Off Topic.. in such case just flag it as "it needs ♦ moderator attention" --> Other --> Write that it belongs to other place and maybe specify why so that it won't get rejected.

[image: screenshot]

You can also add that the target site doesn't appear in the list of "doesn't belong here" but it should be pretty obvious.

Comment: @kiamlaluno what's better in your screenshot? Your one additional flag??

Comment: The previous screenshot used a lower resolution, or less colors; it was distorted too.

Comment: @kia yeah, I usually save screenshots as GIF to not waste space.. old habit. Each and his own, no harm in some extra KB I guess.

Comment: I apologize; I took another screenshot because the other one was distorted. If it were not for that, I would not have taken another screenshot.

Comment: @kia no need to apologize it's alright.. personally I don't pay much attention to pictures quality that's all. :)

Answer (score 6):

While the community cannot migrate directly from SU to Tex, because it isn't one of our normal migration paths, a ♦ can migrate a question to anywhere.

So, if you feel that a question is off-topic on SU *and* belongs on another site that isn't a normal migration path, then please **flag** this question as `it needs ♦ moderator attention` → `other` and specify which site it belongs on *and importantly why it needs moving*.

If the ♦ that processes the flag agrees with you, the question can then be migrated to the target site.

---

As an aside, please never migrate a question to a intermediate site - it is *never* right to send a question to SO (or anywhere else) with the sole intention of re-migrating it from there to a third location.

Comment: +1 for the "never migrate a question to a intermediate site" - very true.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what already said, I will say that the migration should be proposed carefully.
The first rule is "don't migrate crap"; if a question is subjective, then it should be closed, independently if the question suits the site where it has been asked or another site, as subjective questions are always subjective, in whatever site they are asked.