# Downvote that doesn't appear on the question after flag

Tags: bug, status-completed, down-votes, reputation-history

I flagged my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9830652/996493) to be migrated on stackoverflow as suggested by this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/166850).
The moderator told me that the question is too old to be moved and told me that they can just delete it and then i can post the question on the other site. Which I'm completely fine with.

What got me puzzled is that I received a negative votedown on my question after that event as shown on my reputation history. It does not however appear on the question.
I am just very curious why I see the behavior? Is this the price you have to pay for flagging your own post and getting mods attention (which I am completely fine with btw). Is this something i should expect in the future. Or is it because I have done something wrong? 
I don't think it is but could it be a bug?

Here is a screenshot:

> [image]

What confuses me a little bit more is that moderator actually marked the flag as helpful so it doesn't seem like i should receive negative reputation. How bizarre.

> [image: helpful flags]

Comment: +1 Sure enough, it really is 0/0 and not +1/-1.

Comment: Ill just leave this question open for some time maybe someone will know what is going on. If not I will accept Yannis' answer.

Comment: Now in your profile page reputation tab I can see "0" for today, so is this resolved?

Comment: I dont think so since the moderator did not add the status completed when they visited this question. Maybe someone will answer what actually happened. If not i will just mark the answer that is posted and move on.

Comment: -1 those should be freehand circles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a question is closed as Off Topic or Not a Real Question, an automatic downvote is cast.

Your [question was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9830652/revisions) (and then re-opened), and the timestamp of the closure is the same as the timestamp of the downvote. Since the question was re-opened, the vote was cleared from the question and the weird thing is that you still see the -2 in your reputation tab. It *might* be just caching, and will just go away in a few minutes.

Comment: Yes this question wasnt closed when i asked this question. it was just closed now (I asked for it to be closed down before i realized something was fishy) Now that the question got closed down I got my reputation back.. Its pretty confusing

Comment: Reopening would've retracted the vote, IIRC.

Comment: @AnnaLear Timestamps match, it's the auto downvote. Re-opening did retract the downvote (question had no votes), but it didn't seem to retract the -2 (or this might just be [status-caching]).

Comment: @YannisRizos I kinda doubt that it's caching. The only time I've ever seen vote events cached is when there are many of them pouring in.

Comment: well if the question was closed the first time it was closed over 43 minutes ago (cuz thats when I received the down-vote) . So its a little bit over few minutes. Btw my reputation mathed the downvote it was 2 lower it wasnt just in the history. I wish they wouldnt delete the question so i can find out what happened.

Comment: @YannisRizos When I receive an upvote, it immediately shows up on my rep-history unless it's the first event of the day. (and the post's vote count on the profile) But in the rare cases where I've been massively upvoted in a small amount of time, they do appear to be cached up to a minute - but only when I'm logged out. So there *is* caching, but I don't think it applies in this case since it's low traffic.

Comment: @Xitcod13 The downvote and the closure happened at the same time, and yes the downvote was real (automatic, but real), of course it would affect your reputation. The strange thing here is why although the downvote was retracted when the question was re-opened, the -2 stayed in your history.

Comment: this event lasted for 43 minutes at least. Im logged in and reloaded the page multiple times.

Comment: Maybe reopening cause "undownvote" event, and since the time difference was 6 seconds only it simply didn't show? I remember Nick saying that serial events cast rapidly (e.g. user voting then undoing the vote several timed just for fun) are not displayed to avoid noise.

Answer (score 3):

When a question is reopened the automatic community downvote is removed.  However, it wasn't triggering a reputation update as it should have...that's fixed in the next build.

Immediately (not within 5 minutes) you'll immediately see that +2 rep cancellation in the owner's profile.