# The only event during a day is an upvote yet I see negative reputation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation)

I just asked a question about a down-vote which didnt appear in the question but effected my reputation [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152374/votedown-that-doesnt-appear-on-the-question-after-flag/152375#comment437837_152375). It got me to notice another puzzling behavior which probably has a simple answer (and this time I really doubt its an actual bug) Never-the-less I am puzzled so I though i would ask to ease my mind. I have a reputation of -2 on October 16th yet when i click the arrow to see my activity I see that the only activity is an upvote. I would think that if the only event during a day is an upvote the reputation has to be positive no matter what. Maybe somebody downvoted my question and then retracted their downvote? Or Maybe im just going crazy.

here is the screenshot: 
[image: Upvote]

Comment: You have a really buggy reputation page...

Comment: Thats what it seems like to me. I dont know what to believe in anymore. Is this matrix or not dammit!

Comment: @Xitcod13 Have you checked "show removed posts" at the bottom of your reputation tab?

Comment: Perhaps someone took back their upvote after a recent edit or something?

Comment: Ah now i see whats going on. I didnt know some reputation is hidden. Thank you for the comment Yannis. I'll ask a question on how to mark your comment as best answer (only joking... but seriously)