# How to close question that is "Too old to migrate"? And a proposal

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, vote-to-close, off-topic

A question: So, if I come across a question that is too old to migrate, but is clearly off-topic, what am I supposed to do with it? For example, I've seen posts with close votes due to the post being off-topic, but it has since become too old to migrate and thus I can't vote that it is off-topic AND belongs on the other site. What close options am I supposed to use when voting to close?

A proposal: If something is too old to migrate, can it be given a special closed banner (the gray box that displays on closed questions) labeling it as a better fit for the other site. I.e., Under this proposal, I can still vote to close as being off-topic and it belonging on the other site BUT rather than being migrated, it's simply given a publicly-displayed closed reason as being off-topic and better asked on the other site.

Comment: @bad_coder This question is about handling questions which "should" be migrated but are too old to do so, but that concept isn't mentioned at all in that wiki. If anything, I'd expect this to be answered in the migration wiki ([What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249)), but handling this case isn't mentioned there (yet) either.

Comment: @zcoop98 good point, this is actually a feature request for a special banner linking to the site where a question would be on-topic together with the close reason.

Answer (score 3):

You can still flag/vote it as off topic.  If you're voting, you could choose an option that reflects that; with flagging you don't seem to have that option.  I believe there is a discussion somewhere about changing that.

If you're flagging to close, I suggest picking the most appropriate other answer if you can; otherwise use the 'other' box and explain your reason, more than likely the close voters who reviews it will use the right reason.

Comment: Of course this is what I do now, but I'm proposing to leave the other site options up even after it's too old to migrate since all I want to write is, e.g., move to CrossValidated or SuperUser or whatever.

Comment: What you call "move to another site" is what Stack Exchange sites call _migration_. If the question is too old to be migrated, you can close it as off-topic, which is the reason why a question is migrated. If it were on-topic, it would not be migrated.

Comment: @Joe You cannot supply a custom reason when flagging, and close voters won't see which sub-reason you select; they'll only see "off topic". Flaggers can choose any off topic reason to flag an off topic question and get the same results.