# Why was moving question flag rejected?

Tags: discussion, flags, migration, declined-flags

Upon reviewing a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678823/offered-a-job-with-an-empty-job-description) I decided it wasn't appropriate for stackoverflow but could probably fit quite happily on either programmers.stackexchange.com or workplace.stackexchange.com. I remember reading on meta about '[flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/how-to-migrate-a-question)' questions that need moving, if the destination isn't one of those that can be selected through the dialog, so I did so.

However the flag response was:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

I believe that's exactly what I did, but instead the question got closed when it may have been answered elsewhere. I'm trying to figure out why the flag was declined and what I should have done differently?

Comment: Perhaps the seemingly heavy crossposting played a roll? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/205060/offered-a-job-with-an-empty-job-description http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13168/offered-a-job-with-an-empty-job-description

Comment: It's also possible that there were multiple flags on the same post. Moderators can't dismiss flags piecemeal. Your flag may just have been caught up in the wash.

Comment: Which site did you suggest in your flag? If it was Programmers, then the flag was correctly declined, the question isn't suitable for the site.

Comment: @Bart: Honestly at the time I didn't check that, and I could understand that as being a reason - although a comment to say the flag was helpful but the user has already cross posted would have been nice in that situation.

Comment: @Yannis: I suggested that it could possibly go on programmers, or workplace. But the rejection didn't state "no because it wasn't suitable", it says "only raise if it requires moderator intervention"

Comment: @Ian Pure speculation on my part. No clue if that's the reason. Or if the proposed target was bad.

Comment: @Bart: If you have 2 mins add that as an answer - it looks appropriate and if I don't get another reason I'll accept it.

Comment: The question is deleted, can't see any point moving a deleted question.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: It wasn't at the time - It was proposed to be deleted, I flagged it instead to suggest a move.

Comment: It almost certainly would have been rejected by Programmers. I have no idea what the standards are like at Workplace, but I suspect they'd have rejected it too.

Comment: I imagine this is just a case of choosing the wrong reason. "No evidence to support it" would probably have been better. To quell some of the speculation, there were three flags that all suggested being migrated (two of them to Programmers) and the flags were declined before the post was deleted.

Comment: @Wooble The question was [cross posted on The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13168/offered-a-job-with-an-empty-job-description), and... it's doing ok there.