# How can I migrate a post from a stackexchange site to another if I don't have 3K Reputation

Tags: support, migration

This is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229530/automatically-navigate-through-internet-using-a-vpn-or-not-depending-upon-if-the

I think it should be here better: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Is it OK if I just ask in meta.stackoverflow (here) to somebody else do it for me?

Comment: You couldn't move it with 3k+ rep also.

Comment: `"Is it OK if I just ask in meta.stackoverflow (here) to somebody else do it for me?"` No.

Comment: @juergend, I read that here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: @chelder you can **vote** to mmigrate a post to a select subset of sites once you have 3K.  But it needs multiple people to agree.  To move a most outside of the select subset of sites, you need to follow JoshDM's instructions.

Comment: @chelder: Well you could **vote** to migrate with 3k+ rep. But that site is not in the list of migration sites.

Comment: @juergend - It always seems that the site I want to recommend migrating a question to is never in the list of suggested sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flag the question as **"it should be closed for another reason..." -> "off-topic because..." -> "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"**.  Then select your target site from the minimally listed options.

Sometimes the options don't list the site you think it should go to.  If the preferred site isn't listed, click **Flagging** at the top of the floating box, and select **other (needs ♦ moderator attention)**, and note your concerns in the text box.

Then let SO nature take its course.  You can check your flag status on occasion for progress.

Comment: When you do this, be sure to explain why it needs migrated.  You can't just say "move this" and expect it to be moved.  Also, mods on the target site (Network Engineering in this case) would likely have to accept the post.

Comment: I already did, but I cannot check your answer as the correct till 6 minutes :p

Comment: @psubsee2003 - I figured I covered that with "note your concerns".

Comment: @juergend commented: "you can vote to migrate. But that site is not in the list of migration sites"

Comment: @chelder - as stated, "if the preferred site isn't listed, check other (needs moderator attention)".

Comment: @JoshDM you probably did, I was just making sure the "concerns" were explicit.