# Should I migrate all the new questions related to a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, migration

Still there are many posts which are related to [magento](/questions/tagged/magento) in Stack Overflow instead of being in [magento.stackexchange.com](https://magento.stackexchange.com/). As I am working on Magento for a while and observed that I am getting better responses on this new Magento site. So, should I flag these posts on Stack Overflow to migrate them to this new Magento site? Or I should just leave them?

In my opinion, if I migrate these posts to this new site then it will be good for the OP only.

I am asking here because there is a bulk of posts related to the Magento tag still on SO waiting to be answered by someone.

Comment: Aren't most of them too old for migration?

Comment: @Mołot yeah.. I will rephrase my question to all new posts..instead of all posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leave them. Migration should only happen for those questions if they are explicitly off-topic on the site they are on. Not because there is a possible "better" site for them.

And for the particular site you mention, migration is not possible. The site currently is still in beta, meaning migration can't take place.

In general though, a site being created for content that was previously welcome on Stack Overflow does not imply that Stack Overflow should subsequently get rid of any of the content through migration, nor that such questions are no longer welcome there.

And most of them, if migration would be possible, [would be too old (>60 days)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) anyway.

Comment: ok.. so if I see any new posts from next time in SO should I migrate it to magento site?

Comment: No. If they are asked on SO, and they are not off-topic for the site, there is no reason for migration. You could only advice the OP about the site, informing him he might want to migrate. But if you go that route please be careful not to push him into asking a cross-site duplicate.

Comment: One thing to add: Magento site is still in beta. It still can disappear. Forcing migration to beta sites seems bad practice, don't you agree @Mr_Green ?

Comment: @Mołot Ah, hadn't picked up on the Beta thing. In that case migration is not even possible.

Comment: @Mołot yeah I absolutely agree..

Comment: Bart, I just got a valid doubt now.. if we don't migrate to magento beta site then what is the use of having a different site? I mean, that beta site will be gone soon if there are no posts right? IMO, it would be better if we migrate so the user or OP can know that there exists a new site for this.

Comment: No, because the questions are not off-topic for Stack Overflow. You will have to find other ways to promote a new site. And how to do that is best discussed on their Meta. Migrating valid content from SO to a beta site is not the right approach.