# Add notice on deleted questions for posters (previously "Where is a migrated question?")

Tags: feature-request, migration

**EDIT** I was just informed that the question was deleted, not migrated. Then, a similar request follows:

*It would be good to provide a notice on deleted questions for those who posted there (answers/comments)*

I had no way of guessing it was deleted (and I guess the same confusion may happen to others).

---

**Original post** (I think top posting was best here)

There was a question in SO, which was better suited for Mathematics. I had posted an answer, and at the same time the OP flagged it for migration (as per the suggestion of a couple of people, including myself).

While I was editing my answer, the question was migrated (I guess, since I got the "Page Not Found" when tying to post the edit).

I cannot find the post anywhere, in SO or Mathematics (there are no links provided to the migrated question, and it does not show up searching "exponential growth", the topic of the question). I would like to be able to post the edited answer that I wrote. I find no way to give reference here to what the question was (other than my edited answer).

I could not find in Meta how to find those questions either.

Conclusion:

It would be good to provide links to migrated questions for those who posted there (answers/comments). Perhaps by keeping the links in some way in the user profile (hopefully, there is something already in place, and I simply did not find it).

PS: while searching for the question of reference [(using "exponential growth")](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=exponential%20growth), I found quite a few that are also better suited for Mathematics

[How to calculate growth with a positive and negative number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515043/how-to-calculate-growth-with-a-positive-and-negative-number/18395597#18395597)

[exponential growth over time - how do I calculate the increase over a delta-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514449/exponential-growth-over-time-how-do-i-calculate-the-increase-over-a-delta-time)

[How to identify exponential growth within an array of integer data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792818/how-to-identify-exponential-growth-within-an-array-of-integer-data)

...

Comment: One thing I do not understand - if you thought the question was off-topic, why did you answer it? That simply invites more off-topic questions.

Comment: @Oded - I was about to answer one comment by Bart, and another from you, but they were both removed... This is a conspiracy!! :-) I answered the question and at the same time suggested migration. There were others similarly posting comments along the same lines. I thought it was ok. If it is not, then I welcome being educated on this (and perhaps an addition of related info in the FAQs). But I still would like to find the question.

Comment: I have just found [What is migration and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work), which did not show up searching "find question migrated". It mentions a stub, but I wouldn't know where to look for it. An image would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about [Calculate missing gaps with Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435624/calculate-missing-gaps-with-excel/20436669#20436669) (+10k link).

The question was deleted - not migrated, which is **why** you are not seeing it anywhere.

A moderator deleted it following **several** flags, only one of which was a migration request flag.

I can't speak for that moderator, but in general, bad questions do not get migrated and the question itself is centered around Excel, so probably not suitable to Math SE either.

Comment: Yes, that is the question. I guess a similar request applies: *It would be good to provide a notice on deleted questions for those who posted there (answers/comments).* I had no way of guessing it was deleted (and I guess the same confusion may happen to others). Regarding this particular question, I think it was ok for Math (Excel had no specific relevance, it was just a calculation tool), I wonder about the reasons for removal...

Comment: So the text "This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation." on the 404 page doesn't indicate to you that the post was deleted?

Comment: @Krampus - Thinking in retrospective about that message, I understood it as a sign of migration ("removed from Stack Overflow"), which actually agreed with my expectations, and not as a sign of deletion (something like "removed from the Stack Exchange system of sites"). As said, I could not find in Meta how to find migrated questions, so there was no specific "migrated" container where I could look for the question and see that it was not there. I am simply suggesting that a situation like this might be a source of misunderstandings, and it may cost zero to tune SO/SE to account for this.