# migrating question to P.SE

Tags: support

In retrospect, I realize that my question ([Standard way to instantiate objects from an xml config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313629/di-without-a-container-instantiating-objects-from-an-xml-config-file)) is more suited for SE:Programmers. Can I ask a moderator to migrate it there? (If so, how?)

Update: sorry for the duplicated question. Here's the answer I was looking for: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)