# Why migrate a question with an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, support, migration, accepted-answer

This question ["What are offsets in Assembly and how do I use them?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677997/what-are-offsets-in-assembly-and-how-do-i-use-them) was asked on Programmers.SE, answered (by me), and the answer was accepted. It has subsequently been migrated to SO, *along with the rep* from Programmers.

To me, the question and it's answer could equally belong to either site, especially since the answer is completely conceptual. I seems pointless to migrate a question with no compelling reason, especially since people can Google and get hits from anywhere their question is discussed.

The answer to the question ["What is migration and how does it work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) says

> Avoid migrating answered questions. The point of migration is to send the question to an on-topic place when it can get answered. If the OP already has an answer, then we've already defeated the purpose of migration and the destination site won't have anything to do with the question. Avoid migrating these questions unless they are of extremely good quality and risk deletion on the current site.

[er... begin gripe]
This migration doesn't make sense to me, and it appears to violate that guidelines. My answer doesn't really make sense on SO, and on that can be expected to be down voted. I would like it to be migrated back.
[end gripe]

UPDATE
After Werner's question, I flagged it for moderator attention, linking in this post.

Having got no response, I have looked into it and see that it's now closed as [off topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/233824/revisions)!

I don't see how it could be off topic on either site!

Comment: Did you flag the post, requesting a moderator to migrate the question back?

Comment: closure as off-topic at Programmers sounds about right: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773 Also, as I have delete vote privileges at Programmers, I can assure you that there has been indeed "risk deletion on the current site", mentioned in migration guidance (I would cast my vote to delete it)

Answer (score 4):

If the question were migrated back to Programmers, it'd be closed as "Off Topic" by the system, and it'd take 3 votes for them to delete it. Since I'm pretty sure you don't want the question deleted, it should stay put where it will stay open and possibly gather votes.

I'm not really a fan of bouncing a question back and forth. The programmers people thought it was OT for them, so that particular part of the question is best asked *on their meta*. I'm not being coy, [I just have no clue what they're thinking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773). I've given up on trying to understand Programmers.SE.

I'm not going to migrate it back to Programmers because it is on topic for Stack Overflow.  Whether or not they should have migrated it over here in the first place is a question for them.

In general, you are quite correct. We try not to migrate questions that:

- Have an accepted answer
- Have already generated answers on the site they're on that are good answers (we want to keep Good content)

In this case, Programmers loss is our gain: this is a good question, with a good answer.

Comment: clue for those having no clue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: Thanks gnat, I added the link to my answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure most of Programmers have no clue what they're thinking either.  :-D

Answer (score 1):

Programmers moderator here.

I agree with you, this was an unfortunate migration. I don't see how the question is *completely* off topic on Programmers. At first read it might seem like a technical question (thus more appropriate for Stack Overflow), but I think at its core this is a question asking for an explanation of a concept. Conceptual software development questions is all Programmers is about. At best, this is a borderline question and should have stayed where it was originally asked.

Now, the "avoid migrating answered questions" guideline is a good one, but it's not a hard rule. Closed questions on Programmers tend to get deleted sooner than later, so we might bend that guideline every now and then for good questions.

Some further reading:

- [When do these questions belong on Programmers instead of Stack Overflow?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5132/when-do-these-questions-belong-on-programmers-instead-of-stack-overflow)
- [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/162704)

Comment: Conversely, Robert Harvey, who's the highest rep user on Programmers and a Stack Overflow moderator, decided to answer the question on Programmers, instead of voting to close/migrate it.