# Does question-migration fail for questions asked on the wrong SE site?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, migration

If a question is asked on the wrong site (thus garnering very little attention), is the question-migration system going to fail that question?

An example: yesterday I asked a [MySQL question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894948/mysql-update-field-with-x-hours-xx-minutes-from-another-integer-field) on stackoverflow.com.  By the next day, the question had only gotten 6 views and no responses.  In retrospect, I suspect it would get more reviews on dba.stackexchange.com.  I have voted to close the question and move it to dba, but with such a small trickle of visits I'm not sure if/when it will ever be moved.

After reviewing this post on [how migration works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) (4/5 close-votes are required, most votes must come from users with 3k+ points, etc) it seems like a question that is accidentally asked on the wrong site stands a fairly slim chance of being relocated, and a still slimmer chance of having it relocated in a timely manner.  And the natural user response (I can confidently say) is to copy/paste the question on another SE site thus creating duplicate content across sites.

Is there some mitigating system I'm not aware of that addresses this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't fail.

Questions usually get enough views by enough 3k+ users that they'll be migrated reasonably quickly.

However, if you have realised that you've asked on the wrong site and the question has no answers<sup>*</sup> then it would be simpler for you to delete the original question and repost on the correct site.

<sup>* That's not strictly true, you can delete a question if it has an answer as long as that answer hasn't been upvoted, but in this case you'd want to preserve that answer so deletion isn't really an option.</sup>