# Did the migration rules change?

Tags: support, migration

A few minutes ago, I cast the fifth close-vote on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/909487/revisions). It had three votes for "belongs on another site", and one for "This question is not about mathematics, within the scope defined in the help center". Since I know that ["Physics.SE is less fond of homework dumps than Mathematics.SE"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133796/relationship-of-multiple-particles-under-collision#comment273815_133796) and migrating a question of which one does not expect that it fares moderately well at least on the prospective target site seems rather pointless, I also selected "not about mathematics, within the scope", expecting the question to be just put on hold, since I knew from the olden days that migration requires a super-majority of at least four close-voters (that is still written in the [migration faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250)). Yet the question [was migrated to Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133796/relationship-of-multiple-particles-under-collision).

Is that a bug, or must the migration faq be updated?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Migration for all sites except Stack Overflow is (and always has been) on a simple 3:2 majority so this is why the question was migrated in this case.

Stack Overflow is special and in order to reduce the number of poor quality migrations from the site, it requires a 4:1 majority to migrate.

Comment: Is that only _from_ Stack Overflow, or also _to_ Stack Overflow, out of curiosity?

Comment: @DanielFischer - only from Stack Overflow.