# How are migrated questions time ordered?

Tags: support, migration, sorting

Checking [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work), it's not explicit how a migrated question will be ordered in the `newest` queue at the destination exchange, based on the time it was asked, or based on the time it was migrated.

I'm pretty sure it's the time the question was asked -- so if a question is migrated after 2 hours, it will be 2 hours back in the queue at the other end as well.