# Subscribe to tagged questions on all sites except one?

Tags: support, notifications, tag-filters

I am subscribed to the [crypto++](/questions/tagged/crypto%2b%2b) throughout the Stack Exchange network.

Code Review changed the [crypto++](/questions/tagged/crypto%2b%2b), and made it a synonym of another more general tag. I get a fair amount of spurious hits, so I'd like to remove them. I'm trying to setup a notification that effectively says "Tagged Crypto++, and all sites except CR.SE":

[image]

How do I add a filter that says "Tagged Crypto++, and all sites except CR.SE"?

(I would be disappointed if I had to unsubscribe from all of them).

Comment: Here's the related question on Meta CR.SE: [Current synonymization of \[crypto++\]](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5699). Note: getting the synonym removed is not the point of this exercise. As far as I am concerned, the site is free to do what it wants. I'm not getting bogged down in debates about the use of the tag system.

Comment: Or maybe synonyms should not be included in tag subscriptions?  Or there should be a way to manually exclude synonymized tags?

Comment: @psubsee2003 - I was actually hoping for a checkbox as a child of *"All Sites"*. The label should be *"Except these sites"*. But your solutions may work well, too. It might even work better: if CR.SE ever changes the tag back from a synonym, I will still be blocking them; but your solution will pivot and recover automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I get your point to a degree.  Each community is free to handle their own tagging system as they see fit.  But there is some precedent in uniformity in tagging across sites because the migration system greatly depends on tag uniformity.  You can't migrate a post to another site if [at least one of the tags does not exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work/10250#10250) on the destination site.

So I propose an alternative solution.  Simple ignore synonimized tagged in tag subscriptions.  If another community thinks that [crypto++](/questions/tagged/crypto%2b%2b) on their site actually means [cryptography](/questions/tagged/cryptography) then maybe it should automatically exclude sites in which your tag is a synonym.

But to give you some control on this, you should be prompted to with a message that basically says "your subscribed tag was made a synonym of {tag:foo] on site 'Bar', do you want to subscribe to this tag too?"

This should give every user some measure of control over their tag subscriptions.  You don't get notifications when your subscribed tag is a synonym of a different tag on a specific site, but you are offered the chance to subscribe to that tag as well so you can continue to follow that topic on that site.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do. I think the answer to my question is: *You Can't*. If that's the case, then should I turn this into a feature request and accept your answer?

Comment: Another edge case occurred to me: the \[openssl\] tag. On Stack Overflow, it indicates the OpenSSL API in C. On Super User, it indicates the OpenSSL commands, like `openssl [enc|dec|s_client|s_server|verify|...]`.

Comment: @jww now that you mention it, there are probably dozens of edge cases.  The most likely ones are the sites that have no relation to science/tech (like Cooking) compared to any of the IT/Tech/Science/Programming sites.  There may be terms that meeting something completely different.  That does lend some support for your original request.