# What is the correct way to deal with accidentally posting on the wrong site?

Tags: support

Suppose you send a question to the wrong Stack Exchange site. One can't move his own post, and deleting and posting again doesn't seem to be the right maneuver. What is the correct way to behave in that situation?

Comment: What's wrong in deleting and posting on a different site?

Answer (score 8):

You could flag such a post and request that a moderator migrates it.

The migration process is described in [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

And, as commented by @Arch:

> after doing that, post a comment that it's a mistake and you've
>   already asked for migration, so that the site users don't end up
>   downvoting or commenting unnecessarily.

Be aware that moderators may decline your request for migration, unless you make a good case for why a question should be migrated, so the expedient may be to delete and re-post on the other site as [suggested by @Al E.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261645).

Comment: And after doing that, post a comment that it's a mistake and you've already asked for migration, so that the site users don't end up downvoting or commenting unnecessarily.

Comment: Only do this if there are multiple answers or where a single answer has an upvote. In all other cases just delete it yourself/

Comment: @ChrisF Uh, it's nice that you provide input, but it seems your edit goes directly against the answer's initial intention, no matter if more appropriate or not. Commenting if you don't agree with an answer is enough, you shouldn't completely change its message.

Comment: @ChristianRau - I did comment originally, but then thought it better to edit the answer.  PolyGeo will have been notified of the edit (and these comments) so if they're unhappy with the edit they can always roll it back.

Comment: Well, certainly an interesting approach to matter of edits. ;-)

Comment: I thought the edit made too much alteration to my intent, and so rolled it back, and performed a new edit of my own.

Comment: @ChrisF That's not what edits are for. The only time I've found it OK to edit someone else's question or answer is for the purpose of making minor changes like formatting, spelling/grammar/punctuation, or to fix dead links or code. Changing the content is unacceptable.

Comment: @Catija I know what edits are for. In this case I felt that the answer was *almost* complete apart from the information about the rules on self deletion.

Comment: @ChrisF Clearly you were wrong, though... PolyGeo and two others thought the edit was a bit heavy-handed... you can always write an answer that says "what ___ said plus _____", if the first answerer opts not to include your information.

Comment: @Catija Indeed I got it wrong this time, it happens. I've moved on.

Answer (score 7):

If no one has answered, just delete and re-post on the correct site.

People who *habitually* do that may run afoul of post-ban algorithms, but a one-shot is no big deal.