# Migrated question not updated in my favorite tab

Tags: bug, bookmarks, migrated-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592326/sloppiness-in-activity-diagrams) was initially posted on StackOverflow (notice the SO link, though it redirects to Programmers.SE). It has then been migrated to [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331533/sloppiness-in-activity-diagrams) where it's still open. It's now not possible anymore for me to access the question on SO.

When the question was still on StackOverflow, I've added it to my favorites. The problem is that now, when I go to my favorites tab, I see it as [on hold], but it's redirecting to the correct new question on Programmers.SE. See my favorites tab below :

[image: Favorites tab]

The link in the favorite tab is still the one of the question as it was on StackOverflow. The votes view and answers are as well.

Now what I don't understand is why is it displayed in my SO favorite's tab since this link is deprecated ? In my opinion it should have been removed from my favorites automatically during the migration. It could also have been added to my Programmers.SE favorite tab in lieu of my SO's favorite tab.

Is that a bug, a feature or a missing feature ?

Comment: Not really a bug, that's just how the system was built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the favorite could have been removed, but not yet, since migration can take some time to complete: it might get closed on the other site and then migration is rejected after all. The post would return to SO then.

And besides the above, there is an argument to (at least temporarily) keep in in your favorites list on SO. It might have been a question you want to preserve, even though it gets migrated at some point. How would you ever find it back if it gets migrated and removed from your list?

For now, you can go to the [revision history of the post on Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/331533/revisions) and follow the migration path to go to the question on SO. You can remove the favorite from there.

Comment: That's right, many scenarios could have happened. It's correct that it's a question I'd like to preserve, but I think it's strange to show it in the SO tab since it does not belong anymore to SO. However I understand that transferring it to the other site brings the problem of the existence of the other site's account.

Comment: And even more, why should I search in my Programmers.SE favorites list for a question (I think still exists) on SO?

Comment: Isn't there a notification for a favorite question's migration ? I can't remember if I've seen one here, because I was active in the comments so I've been notified on Programmers.SE directly after the migration. If not, it might be a good idea to implement one.

Comment: I don't know. Still, it could get buried in the notification list.

Comment: True. As mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work), the stub (i.e. the question on source site) is left for 30 days before being auto deleted. So in essence, the post is still there, not deleted, and there's nothing to remove it from the lists.