# What are these empty arrows in the migration stats page?

Tags: discussion, bug, migration, 10k-tools

I'm pretty baffled by these entries in the [migration stats page for Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats):

> [image]

What do those migration pathways represent? And, more importantly, shouldn't the UI make it clearer what they mean - at minimum thorugh some text, and ideally through the use of a suitable icon?

Answer (score 1):

From analysis of the [same page](https://chess.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) on [Chess SE](https://chess.stackexchange.com/) (where only [two](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/474/7297) [migrations](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/466/7297) have taken place in the past 90 days), I conclude that this is the site's own Meta. I agree that an icon (the gray version of the main site's icon) would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this shows the migration path between the per-site Meta and the main site.

I checked the [recent closed questions in Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aq%20closed%3Ayes) and I found three within the last 90 days:

- [Why can't I add answers or comments to this thread? Is it closed?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9820) - closed
- [Why was this question deleted?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9465) - marked as duplicate
- [What happened to [username removed]?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9769) - closed

Since [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/209901) mentions that:

> A question can also be rejected by the target community after it has already been migrated if it gets closed as a reason other than duplicate, or gets deleted (usually by the owner) on the target site.

So we can conclude that the *66% rejected* boils down into 1 duplicate (33% accepted) and 2 closed (66% rejected).

I agree with [Glorfindel's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295835/209901) on that the icon should be the gray one.