# Let's move "migrated to" information block to the top

Tags: feature-request, migration

Here's an example of question which is supposedly already have an answer:
[image]

We treat this information relevant and important enough to show at the very top of the question which still can exist on it's own, have some new answers, comment, upvoted etc.

Here's an example of question which has been successfully migrated:

[image]

We literally can not do anything with this post - neither vote nor leave comments or answers - all has been migrated, so the most important thing is to just navigate to the stack where it has been migrated.

Still, we show information banner with relevant link at the bottom of a question which, actually, can be pretty lengthy.

My suggestion is simple - let's move migration information block to the to - and have it exactly where we have "This question already has an answer here" block.

I do recognize that this is done to be consistent with "migrated from" block but I can see no harm in showing "migrated to" and "migrated from" at different places, since there are serving different purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would not be a visible problem for most users—migration stubs automatically redirect to the post on the correct site, unless you append `?noredirect=1` to the URL. One example is [this post on CS Educators that was migrated](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/990/how-to-teach-random-number-generator-algorithms) (check the URL, and the site it takes you to).

As a moderator, the auto-redirects don't happen for you, so you don't see this effect, but for the vast majority of users, they won't be seeing migration stubs at all. This probably isn't an issue that needs fixing as not many users will be able to interact with the migration stubs meaningfully.

[After 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/336144), the migration stubs will be deleted, and during the 30 days, most users won't see them anyway (and if you are getting a noredirect link, you probably know what to expect anyway).

Comment: isn't it 10k users (not just mods) that don't get the redirect?

Comment: @Cai I'm not sure; I have the 10k tools on CS Educators (which are at 2k because it's a beta site), but I still get auto-redirected, and I couldn't find any confirmation over here on Meta.SE about the behaviour.

Comment: Hmm, I can't find anything either but I'm pretty certain that was the case... I no longer have 10k anywhere I don't also have a diamond so can't test though