# How do I transfer my post from a community to another community?

Tags: support, migration

The amount of Stack Exchange Community is increasing rapidly. Even if I was really careful to choose the site I should post my question. However the situation that failing to post the question on most suitable site is still unavoidable. Even though posting it on the currently most suitable zone, when some beta community come to public the best fitted site would be replaced. Is there a efficient way to transfer the post between community without any risk of the loss of reputation?

Is there not, will the supervisor of Stack Exchange consider the possibility to add this feature to Stack Exchange?

Comment: Often the best way is to simply delete your post and post it in a better place. You can also flag your own post for moderator attention and ask it to be migrated, but that's a much harder way.

Comment: If its on a site, its probably fine to stay there. There's no real need to move old questions between sites

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Users with at least 250 reputation can move their own questions to other SE sites whereas users with 3k rep can move other's question as well. Just hit `close` and then select `off-topic` *in your own question*.

[image: Close]

After you hit close you are prompted for a reason. Just select that it belongs to another site in SE network.
[image: SE]

**However** you cannot migrate very old questions.

[image: Old]

Comment: Please do not answer duplicate questions.

Comment: @SonicWizard In https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work which you provided it never states how a user can migrate his own questions. The author just states that a user with 3k rep can do it for you. So it is not a duplicate question(well at-least not of the one you provided).

Comment: That question is an [tag:faq]. I've edited that info into that question, so it's now a duplicate.

Comment: Also, your answer is wrong, as it suggests that users can unilaterally migrate their own questions to other sites, while the procedure here will simply cast a vote to migrate, requiring four other users to vote as well.

Comment: You can not migrate your own question. At most, only five options are in the migrate section and that's **only** if they're actually set up. Many (if not most) sites **do not** have any migration paths set up.