# Can questions be force-moved to a beta from the previously closest matching website?

Tags: discussion, migration, beta-sites

Can a question that previously would have been best matched to site X, be forced (from X) to a beta site Y, a site whose mission is closer to the topic, but has little to no activity? Or would this even happen? This is hypothetical, I'm not referring to an actual event that happened to me or anyone else.

Edit to add example: Imagine a question about physics, related to planets and stars. Previously only on topic at Physics.SE. But the mission statement of beta site Astronomy.SE specifically mentions "astrophysics". Could a moderator at Physics.SE migrate your question against your will to Astronomy.SE which has very little activity?

Comment: Does the SE site you're talking about still exist and is live on the network? Is the question younger than 60 days? In what sort of situation are you asking about this... can you make up a hypothetical example?

Comment: @Catija Edited to add example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not really how we use migrations.

The first question you must ask when considering migration is

> Is the question on topic here?

If the answer to that question is "yes" then no migration will ever happen... or it shouldn't.

We don't migrate questions because they may be a "better fit" somewhere. We only migrate questions if they're completely off topic on the site where they're asked (or in special cases where the OP requests they be moved). Whether a site is in Beta or not is irrelevant to this.

And, in the case of Beta sites - which may be where your question stems - we intentionally limit migrations *because* we want sites to grow naturally with their own, home-grown content. Local users should be able to create questions and answers of their own rather than losing the opportunity (and reputation earned) to migrated questions that may have been asked or answered by people who don't even use the site at all.

And, for this reason, we don't prohibit or close cross-site duplicates (except in extreme cases where they are posted by the same user on two sites with no difference between the questions). If someone has a similar question to one already existent on a site, that's OK! It happens quite often between Movies and TV and Science Fiction & Fantasy, for example.

There's only one case where I can imagine this being used - but even then, I doubt that it would be. For example, if a certain type of question became off topic on one site (that had not been off topic initially) but a significant number of those questions were applicable to another site or became so due to a new site being created, the staff may consider a single bulk migration of these questions to the other site. This would be extremely rare and only done by staff with the express buy-in from both sites.

Comment: I guess that answers my followup question, which would have been: "Can I copy-and-paste that question to Site X if it receives no activity at Site Y beta."

Comment: Is it your question? If so, you can either request migration or (if there are no upvoted answers) it's probably faster to delete it and re-ask it on the other site. If it's not your question, I wouldn't recommend copying and pasting it, rather, asking your own version of it, in your own words.

Comment: There are occasional exceptions in the case of a question being technically on topic but getting no interest or answers. I have on occasion moved such posts to a "more" on topic site where they then got great answers. An example: moving from Sec.SE to Crypto.SE. we now have better guidance as to the boundaries of each, and Crypto is no longer beta, but it worked back then.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they have the tools to do so (for newer questions, see below).

But it general, this won't happen. Questions on site X which are on-topic for site X will stay there, even if the newer site Y might be a better fit. This is a [networkwide policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/295232):

> **Don't migrate for the sake of migration.** We only migrate questions because they are *off-topic on the original site*. It is perfectly possible for a question to be on-topic on multiple sites, but that is not a reason to migrate it elsewhere, unless the OP requests migration. As a general rule, if someone asks a question *here*, and it's on-topic *here*, it should stay *here*.

In any case, questions which are older than 60 days can't be migrated anyway, neither by users voting to close it nor by ♦ moderators.