# Are there scenarios where an historically locked question can be moved to a different Stack Exchange website?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration, seo, historical-lock

Questions may be historically locked when they have a high view count but are off-topic for a given community.

In a situation where a historically locked question would fit better in a **different** Stack Exchange community, can we ask for a migration? Or is it best to **never** move any historically locked question, for SEO reasons?

<sub>(a tiny example could be [The Skyline Problem‍​​](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066234/the-skyline-problem) which may fit better on Code Golf instead of Stack Overflow. But this Meta question is general, so answers/comments shouldn't focus on this specific question)</sub>

Comment: Moderators can't migrate *any* questions that are older than 60 days.

Comment: ... but CMs and developers could.

Comment: They should be moved much more easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions can be migrated no longer than 60 days after they are posted, so these historical questions can't be migrated, regardless of their special lock state - they are just too old.

There is a caveat, though - Stack Exchange employees may migrate questions that are older than 60 days, but this is only done in **very rare** cases, but usually not by request.

See [this FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/223467) for additional details.

Comment: Following the chart from the link, I read "_Does question already have good answers?_" → "_Yes_" → "_**Exercise extreme caution.** Don't vote to migrate unless it's at risk of deletion as is._". So basically, historically locked posts aren't meant to be migrated ever.

Comment: @Cœur my understanding was that SE employees **can** technically migrate these posts, but almost certainly **won't**.