# Migrated question doesn't display a username on the homepage

Tags: bug, migration, display-names

My site recently had a question migrated over to it. The user doesn't have an account on our site yet. It's showing up on the homepage like this:

[image: no username shown next to timestamp]

According to [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work),

> If a user who participated in the question does not have an account on the target site, their username is displayed as plain text until they create an account.

So I'd expect to see something like "Username on other site" or "user1234" next to the timestamp, but instead there's a blank space. (The username does show up in plain text when you click through to the actual question.)

Is this a known issue for certain cases?

Comment: Was the username there before the migration was rejected?

Comment: @Catija yes, I caught the screenshot before it was placed on hold.

Comment: AFAIK, "displays in plain text" only applies to the question page - question lists like the home page don't