# Question was migrated, but users corrupted the title, answered the question, then deleted the whole question and answer: can I migrate it back here?

Tags: discussion, migration

- A few days ago, I posted this question here: [My account seems to have been "destroyed" but not in accordance with the information I am able to find about how "destroying" works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323921/475508).
- I got some useful feedback from some MSE users, and then it was migrated to a different site by a moderator.

I was immediately surprised that my title was changed to something a bit confusing:

[image]

Now the title awkwardly ends with "the information", but what information?
The question was then answered by the same user, who finally gave me an explanation for what happened to my missing question. He said it was deleted for violating the terms of service, so I asked which terms of service were violated. This time I saved a personal copy of my comment, just in case it would get deleted again:

**"Thank you Blue for answering, and thank you @Monica Cellio for helping to get my question in the right place! Blue: Can you please let me know which "terms of service" were violated by my question? Finally, I would very much appreciate if you can send me a copy of my question since I did not think I would have to save my own personal copy. I am just a technical writer and I rely heavily on advice from the "real" experts. In this case I was doing a piece on the new hardware and wanted to clarify some points which were not clear (to me at least) in the one paper I found on the topic."**

A few seconds after I wrote the comment, the whole question got deleted again:

[image]

When I look at the edit history, I see a huge amount of repetitive deleting and un-deleting:

[image]

I found the dialogue much more fruitful on this page (meta.stackexchange.com) and the other page has only left me with lots and lots of new questions and more confusion.

Therefore, ***is there a way to migrate the question back to here?*** I understand that this may be difficult now that the question has been "deleted", but I still appreciate any advice which may be bestowed on me.

Comment: If you want to see/read the comments on the old question, they are here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323921/my-account-seems-to-have-been-destroyed-but-not-in-accordance-with-the-informa?noredirect=1

Comment: Thank you @Mari-LouA, but the bottom of it says "comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews". Can we get it back?

Comment: We moved it cause it was a problem involving one site, and not the network as a whole. Lemme ping the mod in question...

Answer (score 7):

The deletion of the meta question on Quantum Computing seems to be a bug. It was done automatically (note that "Community" is [an automated process](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)) with the reason "User 5818 destroyed" (see the [timeline](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/380/timeline)). Blue, a moderator on that site, only *undeleted* the question. I can't see how having it get deleted (after being manually undeleted) is the intended behavior.

While it's possible for MSE moderators to unlock [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323921/my-account-seems-to-have-been-destroyed-but-not-in-accordance-with-the-informa?noredirect=1&lq=1) here, most of the users here (on Meta Stack Exchange) have no access to deleted questions on other sites. Furthermore, why your account was deleted can only be answered by a [moderator on that site](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) or someone who works for Stack Exchange because this information is not public. This is why the question was migrated in the first place.

Why your new account is suspended is vaguely mentioned on your main site profile page [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/5820/marko): "This account is temporarily suspended for rule violations. The suspension period ends in 6 days." Further details, again, are not public, but I would guess that it's because you recreated your account after it got deleted.

What you should do next is follow Blue's instructions: "For further information or complaints, you may use the [contact form](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/contact)". This form is sent directly to Stack Exchange. (Unlike Meta, this is done privately.)

Answer (score 4):

We could, in theory, undo the migration.

We won't. It's a matter for Quantum Computing, not us, and there's a good many things in the comments that don't add up.

Account destruction is usually very serious. You probably either got caught in the crossfire or there's something we are not aware of. You really need to use contact us. The number of users who that happens to is tiny, and if it's the case you need dev support.

> I was banned from that site, for no reason, it seems...

The suspension process always involves a mod message. You would also get an email. The only situation where this would not happen is if a deleted account under suspension was recreated.

If this was the case, MSE might still not be the right place.

The deletion and undeletion seems to be a bug. Stuff happens.

More or less though, no matter what the circumstances – you probably should be using the contact link.

Answer (score 1):

Once a question is migrated, moderators on both the source or target site are able to clear the migration history, hence unmigrating the question. Another thing that can happen on the target site is: if the question is closed for any reason except as a duplicate, the migration will be "rejected", which will lock the question on the site it was migrated *to* but the question will return to normal on the site it was migrated *from*. For more details see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249).

The reason for Community deleting your question, I do not know. It does not qualify for any of [the roomba rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) and I don't know of any other deletion rules. The important thing is that it was continuously undeleted and that it is no longer being deleted.

So, in short, questions can be unmigrated by moderators *or* from being closed on the destination site, but that's no longer necessary because Community has stopped deleting your question.

Comment: Thank you @Supa for your amazing research on this. However they removed the comment I wrote there, and then gave me a 14 day suspension. All I did was ask one question in a comment (the original comment, is given in this meta.stackexchange question).

Comment: Furthermore, they have changed my title to something that doesn't make any sense anymore. The title on meta.stackexchange.com ends with "but not in accordance with the information I am able to find about how 'destroying' works" but they changed it to "but not in accordance with the information".... but what "information"?  They cut off the rest of the sentence!

Comment: @Marko there must've been *something* in the question or the comment that prompted them to do so. Information like that isn't available publicly, so I would suggest using the "contact us" form to contact the Stack Overflow employees.

Comment: @Marko I agree that edit was not useful at all. You could ping the editor and ask for the reasoning behind it, or just roll it back.

Comment: I was banned from that site, for no reason, it seems. The post from Shog9 says that when you are banned, you receive a notification from the moderator, saying why you were banned, but I did not get one!

Comment: Technically false. Moderators _can_ unmigrate questions.

Comment: @Marko the only reason I can think of that a moderator would do that is if you were a spammer, which you clearly aren't. I really don't see why they didn't contact you about it. If you don't mind other people being able to read it, you could probably ask the moderator with a comment under the answer. But please only do this if you're comfortable with others knowing that information.

Comment: @ArtOfCode really? Where did you hear that?

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle From the mod tools I have :)

Comment: @ArtOfCode Oh, true, I didn't notice you're a moderator. Is it done by closing the question and rejecting the migration, or is there another way to unmigrate?

Comment: No, it's a specific mod tool - clear migration history. Either the source site or the target site can do it, and it frees up the question record on that site to be migrated again elsewhere or for whatever else you want to do with it.