# How to handle a off topic or closed question?

Tags: discussion, new-users, scope

How could one handle any closed or off topic questions?

I have googled many times, browsed through the FAQs.

But seriously I couldn't understand how to get my doubts clarified here,  I mean how to get a relevant answer, rather how to present a proper question.

In short the problems I am facing can briefly stated as:

1. I am not able to post a proper question.
2. I am not able to work on my off topic questions; actually I can't understand what the relevant sites are for my questions.

I am not asking for any question in particular.

But won't it be less troublesome for a new user to post their questions if the sites briefly mention their topics (related)?

Can't we later post these irrelevant questions in relevant sites and get an answer?

E.g. a person (new user) wants to clarify his or her doubt /problem (faced) against cellular networking and he sees a brief intro about Super User. He thought it would be a suitable site, but the site deals with software and hardware concepts.
Oops! The new user's question is closed.

Comment: SO also has a [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: *Can't we later post these irrelevant questions in relevant sites and get an answer.* Technically this is called migration but is riddled with problems and angry users on both sides of the migration. Therefor it is advised to simply delete and re-post on the correct site.

Comment: @rene how do we migrate? Is it simply by editing the site's name?

Comment: You can't migrate on your own. Users with close vote privileges could migrate a post to a small (5) set of sites but it is seldom used. Moderators can migrate a post to any site if the post is less then 60 days old. That is why we tell users to delete the post, find a better site themselves and then re-post. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> actually i can't understand what can be the relevant sites for my questions

There's a list of Stack Exchange sites [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites); also,

> [i]t's often helpful to go to https://stackexchange.com, enter some terms in the search bar in the upper-right, check out the sites that show up in the results, and read their help pages.

<sub>([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/site-recommendation/info))</sub>

If you're still not sure, you can post a [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) question on this very site.

---

> But won't it be less troublesome for a new user to post their questions if the sites briefly mention their topics(related)?

They already do; every site has its own Help Center article ["What topics can I ask about here?"](/help/on-topic). That one links to Meta Stack Exchange, [Stack Overflow has its own version](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), etc.

When you [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), you're also notified about the topic and Help Center articles for further reading:

[image]