# The links in migration banners are inconsistent

Tags: bug, design, migration

A minor annoyance, but an annoyance nonetheless:

[image: Migration origin banner, highlighting the linked words]

[image: Migration target banner, highlighting the linked words]

On the originating question, the first link (*"...migrated to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/443803/rectify-heteroskedasticity-in-r)"*) links to the target question. The second link (*"[Migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) 21 mins ago"*) links to an explanation of what that means.

On the target question, that linking is reversed. The first link links to the explanation, while the second *"[Migrated](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59640381/revisions) 21 mins ago"* links back to the originating question.

Also note that both words linked in the second banner are both "migrated".

This is a bit of a [mystery-meat navigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_meat_navigation), and I consistently get wrong which link is which. That second banner should be revised to:

1. differentiate both linked words
2. make the order of link targets consistent with the first banner