# The off topic notice should include option to migrate in the notice, and allow author to do it

Tags: feature-request, reputation, migration, accepted-answer, off-topic

I recently googled for a topic, found a very similar question of the same topic in Stack Overflow, and posted my question. After a few days nobody had answered it, but I found the answer on my own and posted it, then accepted the answer. Minutes later the question was marked as off topic, and there was a suggestion that this type of question is better suited for Super User community.

In the off topic notice there was no indication that the question could be moved to another community, and being a new contributor, I wouldn't have enough points to do so anyway (unless a change in policy is made in SE to allow authors to move their questions when someone closes them for being off topic). but what should appear there is a button (like the DELETE button that does appear there) The DELETE button doesn't work, by the way, as a vague error message says in general that people have contributed to it. Well, it turns out the contributor of the answer was myself and there was no indication in that message that I should first un-accept my answer, delete it, then delete the original post, or wait for people with higher reputation to move it on my behalf as my hands are tied at that point. It is frustrating for newbies and I suppose many would walk away at that point, but if it's going to be fixed it has to be reported.

Is this something that should be changed? And how to go about it without spending a whole lot of time on it - I don't work for SE and can't spend too much time dealing with it.

Answer (score 9):

(I'm a moderator - so I don't *work* here, and my answer shouldn't be taken as official. However, I'm a moderator on Super User as well, and I'm a long time user, so I think this can be considered at least a little authoritative)

Migrations are a bit... controversial. It kinda worked ok in the old days, generally it's meant to move over *high quality* questions on the wrong site, rather than anything off topic to the 'right' site.

*Commenting* suggesting the 'right' site is a bit annoying. They might *not* be right, and they aren't committed enough to vote to migrate

Since we're on meta, I'd suggest taking a look at our FAQ on [migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

And well, unfortunately - if you're not aware of the scope of the site you asked a question on in the first place, it's difficult to just hand over the ability to migrate. Migration requires *at least 3* of 5 users (or all 3 users on sites with 3 votes for closure) with *sufficient reputation to close* if the destination is one of the migration targets in that site's migration list, so most regular users can't do it unilaterally. A *moderator* can do so (and that's pretty much the highest level of trust) unilaterally or migrate to a site not on that list.

None of this really feels like letting a user to migrate a post on their own, new or not is an intended or desirable outcome.

In theory you *could* flag and ask a moderator to migrate (but SO mods are insanely busy) - but there's some overhead there.

The best thing is to take a look at the help pages and determine if it's the right site in a little more depth *before* posting

Comment: If a user can repost by copying and pasting, it seems a button would accomplish the same thing in a friendlier way. I have no clue why that would be controversial. If the user is blocked on the destination site or something then the migration could be blocked. And if a user does copy and paste because it's not an intuitive GUI, then we end up with duplicate questions as a result. Unless there's a compelling reason against it I'd still vote for the change. Not sure why I get down-votes for suggesting an improvement... Maybe I don't understand the culture but I've only started contributing.

Comment: Why would we want to make it easier. @TedShaneyfelt? 99.99% of the posts that would be elligble for something like this are genuine cr*p.

Comment: Also, because Stack Overflow only requires 3 close votes, *all 3* close voters must agree to migrate or it won't happen.

Comment: ooh, I forgot about that. I do wonder if needing a *majority* might be in the original spirit of the rules though

Comment: @TedShaneyfelt there *is* a compelling reason to to copy and paste - the site rules on the sites are different. A question that *may* be on topic on SU does not necessarily mean "in this exact form". At the very, very, *very* least the tags are not the same, so when re-posting the question new tags should be chosen. The next thing is that some tags might require extra information, so it's not really just copy -> paste -> retag -> correct question. The expectation is that when a user re-posts their question on the correct site, they'll put effort into formulating it correctly for the site.

Comment: “Not sure why I get down-votes for suggesting an improvement...” - Users don’t believe giving a user who submitted a question at the wrong community the ability to migrate their closed question to another community unilaterally.  **I would agree that a user who submitted an out of scope question to a community isn’t the best user to determine if that question should be migrated.** The question you described was apparently deleted

Comment: @TedShaneyfelt Voting on any of the Meta sites is different than on the main sites. On Meta sites, votes much more strongly represent people's agreement or disagreement with the position expressed in the post, rather than just an expression of people's opinion on the quality of the post, although votes can also reflect that. As a consequence, downvotes on Meta shouldn't necessarily be considered negative by the person who wrote the post.