# Can we make the placement of hyperlinks in the migration post notice more obvious?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, migration, timeline, migration-notice

Today when I saw that the post notice for a migrated post looks like this:

[image: migration notice]

Now what struck me as odd was that the word "Migrated" is used as an hyperlink twice. The first occurrence links to the [FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) that explains what migrations is. The second links to the questions timeline.

The placement of the first hyperlink is super obvious and useful. But I feel that the second hyperlink could best be placed elsewhere, namely on the "20 mins ago" part. As then there is a time that links to the **time**line.

This would then be similar to how we link to the revision history for edited posts, but I don't think that would create much confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Different solution, or perhaps an extra but very related request: **Make the order of links in the notices similar.** Currently,  the notice for posts that were migrated away looks like this:

[image]

With the first link linking to the question on Meta Stack Overflow, and the second link linking to the FAQ.

I understand that making them too similar may not be wanted either, as that obfuscates if you're dealing with a post that was migrated **to** vs migrated **from**... but perhaps a bit of bolding for to/from and then just linking the site name to the post on that site works better than shuffling the links so that one notice first links to the FAQ and the other first links to another post. It is a kind of inconsistency I still can't deal very well with, I regularly click the wrong one.