# Answers on migration stub questions include a false notice that they were converted to comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, migration, post-notices

[This question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/10790/why-isnt-recycling-counted-as-part-of-infrastructure?noredirect=1) was recently migrated from Sustainability.SE to [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/68445/why-isnt-recycling-counted-as-part-of-infrastructure). There was already an answer when it was migrated, and as expected, that answer was included with the migration.

However, back on Sustainability.SE, [the answer](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/10791/3379) on the migration stub left behind on the site has this notice:

[image: Answer hidden notice]

> This answer is hidden. This answer was deleted **and converted to a comment** 1 hour ago.

The answer was not converted to a comment, it was migrated and then deleted. The post notice should simply stop after "This answer was deleted."

I confirmed on several other migration stub questions with on Sustainability.SE that that same post notice occurs: [here](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/3159/3379), [here](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/2662/3379), and [here](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/1189/3379). It happens on other sites too, e.g. [here on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382193/?noredirect=1).

Comment: When a question is migrated what remains behind is a stub that will eventually get deleted. [This might help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work/10250#10250): *Answers on the origin site are deleted immediately upon question migration. (This causes a reversal of all associated reputation on the origin site.) The answers will be visible on the destination question.* It’s possible that because of the way those answers are deleted the incorrect post notice is selected.

Comment: @ColleenV I think you are right about the why this happens, but that doesn't take away that the notice that is currently shown is incorrect.

Comment: @Luuklag Absolutely, my comment was intended for information not as a dismissal of the bug report. I am a gifted nitpicker and 100% onboard with making things correct even if only a few folks see them.

Comment: Another manifestation of the same notice: [Answers that were deleted from the low quality queue before April 2014 incorrectly show as "converted to a comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370199/answers-that-were-deleted-from-the-low-quality-queue-before-april-2014-incorrect)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: I've escalated that one as well now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for this report! I've fixed this - the notices on these answers should now correctly describe that they were deleted because the parent question was migrated.

Comment: It looks like [this related bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370199/answers-that-were-deleted-from-the-low-quality-queue-before-april-2014-incorrect) was fixed as well - could you please answer that and mark that as completed too?