# Answers that were deleted from the low quality queue before April 2014 incorrectly show as "converted to a comment"

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, deleted-answers, low-quality-posts

On answers deleted from the low quality posts/answers review queue, there is normally a history event recording when the answer was deleted. However, such history events [only began to be recorded in April 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184568/377214); on answers deleted from the queue prior to that, no history event was recorded.

The deletion post notice on such answers normally indicates that it was deleted from review and lists out the names of the reviewers. However, as far as I could tell, that only worked for answers deleted from review *after* the above change to record history events on such answers. On answers deleted before that, it would just show as "deleted" with no explanation, possibly because fetching the reviewers out of the history would be more difficult.

However, it seems that today, such answers (deleted before the change) are now incorrectly showing as "converted to a comment". Looking through the history of the parent questions and other answers on each example task I could find, I couldn't see any evidence of any of these answers being comments, and I find it unlikely that each one was individually deleted after the fact.

Here's an [example task](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/13162). The timestamp of the deletion and supposed comment conversion is the *exact* same time as the last reviewer recommending deletion:

[image]

Can the deletion notice for answers deleted from review prior to April 2014 be made to work the same way as for those deleted after? If that is too technically difficult to implement, can the prior behavior of simply showing as "deleted" (without incorrectly stating that it was converted to a comment) be reinstated?

Comment: See also: [Answers on migrated questions include a false notice that they were converted to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368968/answers-on-migrated-questions-include-a-false-notice-that-they-were-converted-to). It seems like that message is some sort of default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was solved as a part of my resolution of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368968). Thanks for reporting!