# Confusing email after question migration

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, email, migrated-questions

I recently posted a question ["We encountered a pro​blem processing your request" when downloading ISO from Windows Insider Program](https://superuser.com/questions/1695358/?noredirect=1) on Super User which was then migrated to Web Applications. A day later, I received an email about this:

[image]

and a couple of things stand out:

- There is no **Feedback**: (perhaps because there is no 'post owner guidance' for this close reason, which makes sense) – perhaps it's better to leave it out
- When I click the 'comments' link, I get redirect to [its new location](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/161876/we-encountered-a-problem-processing-your-request-when-downloading-iso-from-wi), but there are no comments ...
- The mail mentions editing the question, but that is not possible because it's locked (on Super User). The correct way to get it reopened on Super User would be to contact a moderator. (FWIW, I've already spoken to the one who did the migration, explained that I deliberately posted it on Super User because it's about obtaining an operating system, but I have no problem with the migration *per sé*.)

Perhaps all of this can be solved by not sending emails like this for migrated questions? You already get an inbox notification for migrations, that should be sufficient. There's nothing I need to do right now, so basically the mail is noise.

Comment: Also...  I don't think any of us kinda knew about it.  Like no idea at all

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I didn't know about the feature, but [apparently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405190/4751173) it already exists since February. It's probably only active on a handful of sites, I've never received such an email after a closure on Meta.SE.

Comment: @Glorfindel I've received an email after a Meta.SE closure that happened last week. Maybe moderators don't get closure emails?

Comment: @Smitop my guess is that they've turned it on for other sites than SO only recently. But frankly I have no idea, I've missed the announcement (if there was any).

Comment: Assuming we want to send an email, it looks like the best option is for us to create a completely new email for migrations entirely - it gives us a way to explain migration to less-engaged users who are more likely to have questions migrated. We've got a draft going and will update here once we build it in. Thanks so much for bringing this to our attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that we could skip those entirely, but first, we're gonna try out having a migration-specific email. The email content was updated to remove the "it is closed" verbiage and add links to the question on its new home. The format goes roughly like this:

> ### This question was migrated to another Stack Exchange site.
>
> **Question:** $oldLink$
>
> **Feedback:** Because we have over 170+ subject sites on Stack Exchange, sometimes good questions can get a better answer from a different site than they were originally asked on. Community members on $sourceSite$ have determined that your question is a better fit for $targetSite$.
>
> **What should I do next?**
>
> - [Visit your question]($newLink$) and join $targetSite$ to get notifications about new answers and comments, accept an answer, and earn reputation.
> - Learn more about [question migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I am not planning to test it, though :)