# Wrong instructions in email about duplicate question

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, email

I just got [another email](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374561/295232) because [one of my questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374671/295232) was closed as a duplicate. The mail ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM5T1.png)) suggests me to

> **Select the suggestions that answer your question.** Your question will be associated with these links so future visitors can easily find the answer. Your question will be marked as a duplicate and become visible to the public again.

This may be appropriate when the question has close votes, but not when it's already closed (which is when you get this email). Also, "become visible to the public again" – I assume that's only for new users on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Agreed, not really much to do with that suggestion on an already closed email.

Just removed that line altogether ... and formatted the, now lone, bullet as regular text.

[image: Closed as Dupe Email Updates]

Thanks for the report!

**See Also**: [Email notification about a question getting closed (as duplicate) is confusing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405190/1366033)

Comment: I haven't tested it yet (I hope not to post duplicate questions anymore) but I'll accept it anyway. Thanks for fixing it!

Comment: One of those rare cases where you don't really want to repro :) Thanks for the identifying and suggesting!

Comment: You could also make the email pluralisation aware. In case there is only 1 duplicate in the notice this text doesn't make all too much sense.

Comment: @Luuklag: It seems like the simplest rephrasing that addresses that issue would just be "[...] suggested **one or more** similar questions** [...]".

Comment: Whatever works @V2Blast. But then it would be question(s).

Comment: Part of the text is: "Confirm that none of the suggestions answer your question. Your question **will remain hidden** for now.". --- It was never hidden, and isn't now; it got a few upvotes after being closed. (Thanks) --- It would be better to receive the email an hour or two after closing (if not after the 2nd confirming close vote), the next day is less helpful; better late than never, I guess. --- Almost all the email's text needs a once-over.