# Comments on migrated questions still show up in my site-specific "all actions" tab, even after the comment is deleted at the migration target

Tags: support, comments

I understand that I lose connection with a comment when it is migrated to a site at which I am not a member.

However, I also notice that even where that comment is deleted at the target site, the comment still appears in my "all actions" tab in my profile at the source site. Even weeks after the comment's deletion.

How can I have these removed from my "all actions" tab at the source site?

Comment: Per our [migration FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work), when a question is migrated, the original question on the source site is left behind as a stub for at least 30 days, and any comments made on it are preserved. If you copy the old link to the question and put `?noredirect=1` there, you'll see that a copy of it still exists on the source site with your comment. Once the source stub question is automatically deleted, the comment will disappear from your source activity history.