# Downvoted migrated question still affecting reputation

Tags: support, reputation, migration

I asked [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/469040/meaning-of-satisfiable-network-path) on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour).  It was admittedly off-topic and appropriately migrated to Stack Overflow.  However, the downvote I received before it was migrated remains as does the hit to my reputation.  Can this be remedied?  There isn't any option for me to delete the question.

Comment: You have to wait 30 days after migration, plus a few more days, per our FAQ [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work): *The question [on the origin site] is left as a stub, or pathway to the new site, for 30 days, after which it is automatically deleted by a weekly script. During this time, the stub question will be locked to preserve the post in its original state, preventing comments and votes. (Again, this deletion causes a reversal of all associated reputation on the origin site.)*

Comment: The reason behind waiting 30 days for the stub to be deleted is if the migration gets rejected by the destination site by them closing it: it allows for the question's answers to be "returned" to its origin site. (However, after 30 days, the question's basically "settled in" to the new site, so closing it there will have no further effect.)

Comment: It looks like the question on Ask Different was deleted ten days ago. Confirming you got your reputation back there - did you?

Comment: Yes, I did!  All good.